# vim supertab autocomplete when searching with '/'

Tags: vim, autocomplete

I don't mind too much using `ctrl+p` to autocomplete, but when I use it in the search mode (when typing `/`), it does a very poor job of autocomplete and only cycles through previous searches.

Is it possible to use the supertab autocomplete functionality when I'm searching for something with `/`, so that I can do proper autocomplete for words I haven't searched for yet?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I use the [cmdline-complete](http://www.vim.org/scripts/script.php?script_id=2222) plugin. You can remap the default keys to anything you want.